# Leaflet.draw how to draw circle with two mouse clicks

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.draw

I'm using `leaflet.draw`

By default, to draw a circle :

1. You should click on map(this will be the center of the circle)
2. Then drag the mouse to draw the radius of a circle.

https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/docs/examples/full.html

How can I change this to double click?

1. First, click will put the center
2. Second, fixed the radius?

Thank you

Comment: You can use [Leaflet-Geoman](https://github.com/geoman-io/leaflet-geoman/) there is the circle drawing implemented like you want